# After triggering a Jenkins job remotely via a Bash script, when should I retrieve the job id?

Tags: bash, jenkins, agent

I already built a script trigger_jenkins_job.sh  which works perfectly fine for now. It’s composed mainly of 3 functions:

```
input_checkpoint 
run_remotejob         #: Running Jenkins job remotely using Json api.
sleep 10              #: 10 sec estimated time until pending duration is over 
                         #and Jenkins job start running, i.e. a given slave was 
                         #assigned to run the job.
get_buildID           #: Retrieving build state, last build ID and last stable 
                         #build ID using
```

The problem is I want to get rid of that sleep 10 seconds. And in the same time, I want to be sure before executing the function get_buildID that the remotely- triggered job is actually running on a node.

That way I will be retrieving the triggered job’s id, and not the last one in the queue before triggering that job.

Regarding the Jenkins file of the job, I specified:

```
agent {
        label 'linux-node'
    }
```

So, I guess the question is, I need some how from by bash script, to test if linux-node is running the remotely-triggered job, and if yes I execute the function get_buildID.

Comment: Make your run_remotejob    return a value of true if its running and based on that you can trigger the rest of your jobs and no need to wait for anything

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the sleep command and use the `wait` command.

Comment: No it's not about that, the problem is I should not run get_buildID function before making sure that the agent linux-node is running the remotely-triggered job

Comment: Ah, I see.  The other common way of doing this is to use /tmp files.  Essentially, have the linux node set a /tmp file, and then have your script check to see if that file exists.  If it does, you know the process has kicked off.

Answer (score 0):

If you are triggering Job with tokens,it command itself should return you buildNumber.
Another way could be REST API. Please see "nextBuildNumber" field there (if build is still pending) else "number"